# How to define an alternative default value (to None) for an optional parameter of a python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a function with multiple parameters, some of which should be optional. I want the parameters to be able to work with numpy arrays. If the parameters are given, when the function is called, I want to perform operations.
I'm trying to use something similar to this (the actual operation is more complex):

```
def func(a, b = None, c = None):
    a*2
    if b != None:
        b*2
        if c != None:
            c*2
```

This works well, as long as I don't pass an array into these optional parameters. When I pass an array for b or c  the `if b != None` doesn't work without `any()` or `all()`. If I change it, it does work when all optional arguments are used, but no longer if they're not used.

Is there a way to use something instead of `None` which will allow me to use an if-statement for the default value/object as well as an array I pass into the function.

It should look similar to this (with something different than `None`):

```
def func(a, b = None, c = None):
    a*2
    if b.all() != None:
        b*2
        if c.all() != None:
            c*2
```

I would also appreciate any better ways to simply ask if an optional parameter was given to a function.

Comment: You should use `is not` which checks the identity and works with numpy arrays as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `!=` here; you are testing if all values of an array are not equal to `None`. Instead, use `is` identity testing:

```
if b is not None:
    # ...
```

`is` and `is not` do not broadcast across an array.

You should *always* use `is` and `is not` when testing for `None` anyway, because it is guaranteed to be a singleton.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed!